# Evenly space li's using percentages

Tags: navigation, html-lists, responsive-design

Is there a way to evenly distribute elements? I'm working on a reponsive design and want to evenly distribute `li`'s in a menu.

HTML

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="freebies.html">Freebies</a></li>
        <li><a href="lookbook.html">LookBook</a></li>
        <li><a href="gift-finder.html">Gift Finder</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

## navigation ul{

margin:0;
padding:0;

}

## navigation li{

```
display:inline-block;
font-size:30px;
font-family: 'delicious_smallcapsregular';
```

}

## navigation {

width:100%;
}

## navigation li a{

```
color:#737373;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using margin in %'s like this;

```
#navigation li{
display:inline-block;
font-size:1.8em;
margin:0 2%;
font-family: 'delicious_smallcapsregular';
list-style-type: none;
}
```

And not only margin but also keep reducing `font-size` and `padding` to get more responsive and equally distributed for every device.